# IBM MQ Transport Type Managed Work but Client Does Not Work

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

My client connection is working with

```
MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED
```

but doesn't work with:

```
MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT
```

as I get this error:

> return MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED for MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT

I want to control commit and rollback so I decided to change the transport type, but it doesnt support it. Why would this be?

I am using dll => amqmdnetstd.dll 9.1.2 at .netcore project

Code summary

```
Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, "5577");
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard support `TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED` Mode only.

See the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [IBM MQ 9.1.x>IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing .NET applications>Getting started with IBM MQ classes for .NET>Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm#q132490_)

> **IBM MQ classes for .NET Framework and IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard features**
>
> The following table lists the features applicable from IBM MQ Version 9.1.1 for IBM MQ classes for .NET Framework and IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard.
>
> Table 1. Differences between IBM MQ classes for .NET Framework and IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard features
>
> ```
> Feature         | IBM MQ classes for .NET Framework | IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard
> ----------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------
> Transport Modes | Managed, Unmanaged, and Bindings  | Managed
> ```

If you want to use `TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT` Mode you would need to switch to `amqmdnet.dll` which only works with .NET Framework and has been stabilized by IBM, see IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [IBM MQ 9.1.x>IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing .NET applications>Writing and deploying IBM MQ .NET programs>Using the stand-alone IBM MQ .NET client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.htm)

> From IBM MQ Version 9.1.1, the amqmdnetstd.dll library is available for .NET Standard support on Windows (see Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard. **The amqmdnet.dll library is still supplied, but this library is stabilized; that is, no new features will be introduced into it.** For any of the latest features you must migrate to the amqmdnetstd.dll library. However, you can continue to use the amqmdnet.dll library on IBM MQ Version 9.1 Long Term Support or Continuous Delivery releases.

Comment: **The IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard support TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED Mode only.** is this a restriction to use ` queueManager.Backout(); `  ?

Comment: Managed mode should support SYNCPOINT and commit/backout, can you explain what you are asking?

Comment: I want to use queueManager.Commit() and queueManager.Backout() get 10 messages from queue and run Backout() code but rollback does not work. If I run Backout 10 message should stay queue but not. client transport type is MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED    getOptions are MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING

Comment: Can you open a new question and show a sample of code in your question.  MQOO are not GET options,  they are OPEN options,  I think you are mixing up two things.   This however would be a new question,  I have answered your original question.

Comment: New Question opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190371/how-can-i-use-backout-and-commit-at-ibm-mq-on-net-core-platform @JoshMc